# Chat heartbeat with AJAX (PHP and JQuery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have developed jquery live chat between users.

I want to know if the heartbeat I planned is saving resources or wasting a lot?

this is the heartbeat code:

```
function chatheartbeat(){
    var dataString = 'action=chatheartbeat';
    $.ajax({
        url: "../chat.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(items){
            if(items != 0){
                $.each(items, function (i, elem) {
                    if ($("#chat_"+elem.from).length > 0) {
                    $("#chat_"+elem.from+" .chatmessege").append('<div class="chatboxmessagehead"><span>'+elem.from+':</span><a>'+elem.timee+'</a></div><br><div class="chatboxmessage">'+elem.msg+'</div>');
                    $("#chat_"+elem.from+" .chatmessege").scrollTop($("#chat_"+elem.from+" .chatmessege")[0].scrollHeight);
                    }else{
                    startchat(elem.from);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    setTimeout('chatheartbeat();',2000);
}
```

Comment: so your chat only works every 2 seconds?

Comment: "is saving resources or wasting a lot?" compared to what?

Comment: Side note: Do **not** pass strings to `setTimeout`, it uses `eval` (and that's `evil`)!  Pass functions: `setTimeout(chatheartbeat, 2000);`.

Comment: yes.... every 2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on how many users you are dealing with and how much do you want it to be fast.
Making an AJAX request that fetch data from a Database is usually considered way too much. You should go with *at least* 5 seconds span between a call and another, obviously depending on your server speed and user capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Developing live chat through simple ajax and php is not the way to go. 
You have to use node.js in order to achieve realtime chat system. facebook is using it.

The problem with regular ajax and php is that you have to query the server every 2 or 3 seconds to check wether new data is available and that puts too much load on the server.

Node.js is the way to go.

Comment: you can use socket.io which is a framework of node.js. so why use socket.io? well there are different browsers and you need alot of code to support all those browsers. so what socket.io will do is it will automatically choose the best solution based on the users browser wether their browsers support web sockets or not. Long polling is not the solution to your problem it puts burden on the server.

Comment: I agree with Muhammad, polling versus socket.io.. socket.io in this case would be best

Comment: While your answer is valid, I don't think is complete right. I mean, if you are planing to handle a lot of traffic like facebook do, yes it's **necessary** to go for that kind of solution, but if is a simple one with little amount of movement the proposed solution will work ok without generating an appreciable load. Why bother to add a new layer (install, configure and maintain) if can be done a lot more easy?